# How to start an ordered list at specific number if using psuedo elements?

Tags: css

Hello I have a page that consists of three ordered lists, there is content in between them so it is necessary to split them up into three different lists. I would like to control the number that the second and third ordered list starts with. I am using a psuedo `:before` for my ordered list so I can customize the numbers.

Here is my CSS:

```
.postid-1028 ol {
    counter-reset: item;
    list-style: none;
}

.postid-1028 ol li {
    padding-left: 55px;
}

.postid-1028 ol li:before {
    content: counter(item) ". ";
    counter-increment: item;
    left: 20px;
}
```

Is it possible with some css or jquery to start the second list at a number of my choice like 7 instead of 1?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a number increment in your `ol` element.

The `counter-reset` function has an optional integer value (0 by default), which you can use to start counting from that number:

`counter-reset: [ <identifier> <integer>? ]`

---

### CODE SNIPPET:

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: my-counter 6;
}
li {
  counter-increment: my-counter;
}
li::before {
  content: counter(my-counter);
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: awesome, that is exactly what i was looking for. thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. I re-read your question and it does not matter if you have content between `ol` elements, you can still use one counter, just define your `counter-reset` on the `body` selector. Demo [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/7wodwL4r/)